# Re-running all cells in Colab/Jupyter when re-opening

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, runtime

I am currently working on a CV-based AI image-classification model in *Google Colab* (though this problem is also present in Jupyter).
The problem is that training the model takes quite a lot of time (actually, >6 hrs.) and after the model is trained and all the cells have run, all works well and fine, but after closing chrome/jupyter, **the executed cells do not get saved** and on re-opening, *I have to re-run all of them again* to make any further changes or check the model.

Saving the model doesn't work. I have it saved both on `Github` and `Drive` but only the code get saved.
I was hoping for a way or a trick to help save the cells in the executed state so that they don't need to be re-run again and again. Maybe, it has something to do with runtimes and sessions but I seriously don't know anything about them so I knew better to change anything.

*P.S.- This problem is really annoying and time-consuming, especially if you have hundred cycles to go through to train your model. An answer/trick would be really appreciated.*

**Thanks!**

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Keras has inbuilt funcionalities to save models: [save model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model)

Comment: Yeah, that is all fine. I have saved the model and import it in my project. But the rest of the script needs to still be re-run

Comment: why is there a need to rerun?

Comment: Well, I got the answer on a site. There is no way to save executed cells, you have to re-run them. This is the link, I hope it also helps you understand the question better. Also, since I got the answer or the lack thereof, there is no need for this question to exist... LINK: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-notebook/4714

Comment: What prevents you from saving the trained model in a file and loading it from that file when rerunnning?